# Conditions of existence for an annulus' embedding with special properties

Tags: differential-geometry

Well, I have this issue and I'll be very thankful to any advices, hints or recommendations.

Suppose we have a domain $D$ in $\mathbb{R}^3$ which is described by inequalities:
$$ x^2 + y^2 \geqslant 1, \; 
\left ( \frac{x}{\lambda_1} \right )^2 + \left ( \frac{y}{\lambda_2} \right )^2 \leqslant 1  \; (\lambda_{1,2} > 1) .$$
What I'm doing is trying to construct (or to say, is it possible to construct) a surface knowing few facts of its geometry. These facts are:

1. Topologically this surface is an annulus' embedding. One component of border belongs to $x^2 + y^2 = 1$ and another — to $\left ( \frac{x}{\lambda_1} \right )^2 + \left ( \frac{y}{\lambda_2} \right )^2 = 1$
2. This surface has a set $\mathcal{A}$ of points where it is tangent to plane $z = 0$. Set $\mathcal{A}$ is finite and its points are the only surface's points of tangency to $z=0$. Also, all tangencies are one-sided: 
   it means that locally they are like a tangency of $z =  y^2 + x^2$ ("above") or $z = -y^2 - x^2$ ("below") to $z = 0$ at origin. All points from $\mathcal{A}$ belong to the interior of domain $D$. The side of tangency is known at any point, it can be "above" or "below"
3. Each point $a$ from $\mathcal{A}$ is equipped with unit normal vector $\vec{n}_a$, it can be $(0, 0, 1)$ or $(0, 0, -1)$

So, I have the description for surface: set $\mathcal{A}$, with description of tangency ("above"/"below") and normal vector at each tangency point. The goal is to construct surface which satisfies properties $1, 2$ and which field of unit normal vectors agrees with $\vec{n}_a$ at each $a \in \mathcal{A}$.

These properties are what is known about hypothetical surface. Nothing is assumed about other critical points. The surface doesn't need to be a graph 
$z = f(x, y), \; (x, y) \in D \cap \lbrace z = 0 \rbrace$.

I have very few ideas and observations at this moment. One observation is that Eulerian characteristic of annulus implies the presence of saddle critical points. I also thought about something like Reeb-graph techniques, but that thought wasn't too deep.

Thanks in advance for any help. Feel free to retag or add tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a schematic of how to construct such a surface as a deformation of the annulus; my picture is only 2D but hopefully you see what it's meant to look like.

[image]

Here $n$ is the direction of the normal and $t$ is the side of tangency. Making the intuitive deformed discs that match these cross-sectional curves (e.g. just surfaces of revolutions for the first two, something looking like an elephant's trunk for the last two) gives you these "basis discs" whose only tangency to $z=0$ is at the designed point, with all four possible combinations of $n$ and $t$.

Start with the flat annulus $D \cap \{z = 1\}$. Since $\mathcal A$ is finite and therefore just a collection of isolated points in the (2D) interior of the annulus, you can choose pairwise disjoint Euclidean discs contained in the annulus that are centred on the points. Then just replace each of these discs with the corresponding "basis disc", and smooth everything out near the boundary circles.

Comment: Yep, I've caught the idea, thanks. Looks great and simple! Could you clarify one moment, please? What theorem of continuation you exactly meant in the last step? Was it continuation of $C^0$-function/mapping from compact set and then smoothing or $C^1$-continuation?

Comment: @Evgeny: I hadn't even thought it through that far. I'd probably use a smooth partition of unity to interpolate between the flat annulus and the basis discs.

Comment: Ah, it's probably a good way to do this too. Thanks again!